# How to stop LibreOffice Draw from converting barcodes to numbers when opening a PDF file?

Tags: libreoffice, fonts, pdf, barcode

I am using LibreOffice Draw to edit a PDF document which has a barcode printed in it. Draw decodes the barcode and replaces it with numbers as soon as I open the document. The decoded text is of *3of9Barcode* font type.

I need the barcodes left in place. To do that I tried disabling/removing the font type using *font-manager* but it wasn't listed there. Also can't find any option to disable barcode reader. Need help.

Comment: Your mistake was in thinking the barcodes were being converted to text.  It was actually the other way around, text converts to barcodes if you have the proper font.  P.S. 3 of 9 is not the best choice for a barcode technology, unless you're stuck with it for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [mikekaganski's answer](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/how-do-i-keep-barcodes-on-my-document-in-libreoffice-draw/50512/2) to the similar question [how do i keep barcodes on my document in libreoffice draw?](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/how-do-i-keep-barcodes-on-my-document-in-libreoffice-draw/50512) in [ask.libreoffice.org](https://ask.libreoffice.org):

> [...] the barcodes are in fact texts using some specific “barcode” font absent on your system.

You mention that the font you get for the barcodes is *3of9Barcode*, so try downloading the font and see if this works for you. Do the following:

1. Download the *3of9Barcode* font from here: https://www.dafont.com/3of9-barcode.font
2. Extract the downloaded zip file.
3. Copy the `3OF9_NEW.TTF` file from the extracted directory to `~/.fonts` (create the directory if it's not already present).
4. Try opening your PDF again.

I suppose that the above should work. I cannot be sure since you haven't provided a sample PDF to test.

Comment: This was really important for me. Can't thank you enough for this!

Comment: You're welcome!! I'm really happy I could help!! :D